# Memory allocation of structure inside a Class in c#

Tags: structure, heap-memory, value-type, stack-memory, reference-type

Where the structure and primitive data stored if they are part of a reference type ?

e.g

```
 public struct MyStruct()
   {
       int x=10;
   }

   class MyClass
   {
     int x=10;
     Object y=10;
     MyStruct struct1;
   }
    MyClass obj= new MyClass();
```

Where all the inside members of obj reference Object will be stored in memory Stacks or Heaps ?